# Database Performace - 1:1 relationship or merge the table?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, database-performance, one-to-one

Based on performance, would it be better if two tables with 1:1 relationship has their column all merged into single table?

For example I have `Users` and `Admins` table. Admin shares all columns from Users but has its own specific columns like `permission`

so do I design the database like this (version A):

```
USERS         ADMINS
- id          - id
- username    - user_id
- password    - permission
- ...         - ...
```

or like this (version B)

```
USERS
- id
- username
- password
- permission (left empty when it's normal user)
```

Version A is cleaner but does version B is much faster? Which approach is more common?

Thanks

Comment: There is *no* "performance" problem until there is a performance profile - and you are free to run performance tests. Keep the model *normalized* and extensible. Proper indexes (and a decent database) mitigate most all such trivial "performance" issues.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for the reply. By 'extensible' does it mean Version A is better?

Comment: There is also option C. `Users<-UsersPermissions->Permissions`. But out of the two above I would probably go with A, as I have done so historically in the past. It has the advantage that the `admin_id` can be used as a simple FK/DRI - but if such is appropriate depends on the system design.

Comment: @DarcCode No, it means it depends on your database usage and none of us can adequately answer your question. Personally I would put a foreign key in admins to point to the user record rather than duplicating all the columns in the user table.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thanks, I also prefer cleaner version. I think I'll go with version A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaner solution should be given preference over faster hacks. However, in your case `Admins` seem to be only a role of the `Users`, not a separate entity. Merge the tables when as it is only a role that can be indicated by a column in the table. Use another table only when it is a separate entity.

So, in your case it should be "version B".

Comment: The permission can be something like low-level, high-level, super-admin, etc. So does Version A better for that case?

Comment: No. You may use bit pattern to identify what level permission it is. For example - binary value 100 is super admin, 010 is high level, 001 is low-level.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no need for another entity 'table' for Admins,
Just add attribute 'Admin Permission' in USERS entity so Version B is the right one here.